# Parameters are not binding in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate pdf from jasper reports. But pdf file is generated but parameters are not reflecting in pdf. Here is my code:
firstPage.jrxml file code:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="firstPage" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9e04b773-6665-446a-837f-863d3d7ce312">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="11"/>
<parameter name="data" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="209" y="27" width="100" height="20" uuid="0fde4029-d805-448f-a443-a436a41865d1"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{data}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="190" splitType="Stretch"/>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="78" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```

And Spring java code:

```
Resource resourse = new ClassPathResource("/jasper/firstPage.jasper");
    Resource imgResource = new ClassPathResource("/img/Big_India.jpg");
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("data", "Rks");

    try {
        data.put("imagePath", imgResource.getURL().toString());
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(resourse.getInputStream(), data);
        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "/home/rakesh/Desktop/ss.pdf");
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And spring file structure is :[image]

Comment: Did you pass the datasoure? Did you try to add staticText to Title? Is it ok?

Comment: Here i am passing text from java to jrxml. for exapmle its static text only. This is simplest thing

Answer (score 3):

Seems you miss a `DataSource` which is a container storing structured data. Jasper Report engine retrieve data from a `DataSource` while generating the report.

There are a number of `DataSource` provided by Jasper such as `JRResultSetDataSource`, `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` and `JRMapCollectionDataSource`. Each can retrieve data from different data source in order to fill the report fields.

In your case, if your do not need to fill data into tables, you can simply use a `JREmptyDataSource`:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(resourse.getInputStream(), data, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

For more details about data source, you can have a look to [JasperReports - Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/)